# How to jump 2 pages before using iron router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I want to jump to the previous page using iron router. Normally, I would have used the `history.back()` function but in this case, I use yield templates.

The page I am in is reached using `myWebsite.com/page` which redirect to `myWebsite.com/page/sub-page` in order to display the default yield content. Tell me if it is not clear enough, I can edit and provide the code.

To sum it up, my previous page is 2 pages behind. I tried `history.back(2)` or `history.back(-2)`but it does not change anything to the normal behavior of the function. How should I do?

I could point directly to the second page but if the user uses the `myWebsite.com/page` url to access it, my back button would not work.

**EDIT**: It appears that it was my condition for checking if the history was at least 2 pages which didn't work. Moreover, I should use `history.go(-2)` instead of `history.back()`

I will post a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
var numberOfEntries = window.history.length;
//check if the history is big enough
if (numberOfEntries>2){
     // if it is, jump two pages before
    history.go(-2);
    }else {
    //if it is not, use the default path
    Router.go("home");
    }
```